# Execute stored procedure with parameters

Tags: parameters, plsql, execute, procedure

I have stored procedure and should get its result.

From debugging of Java part:

```
return getJdbcTemplate().call(newCallableStatementCreator(inParams), getDeclaredParameters());
```

I've discovered procedure's name and its parameters.

How can I execute this procedure with these parameters from e.g. Oracle Sql Developer.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the procedure's name and parameters as you have discovered them. You will need them to run the procedure from SQL Developer.

Answer (score 24):

In SQL Developer you can run a stored procedure from the SQL Worksheet window like this:

```
exec myproc (myparam1 => 'a', myparam2 => 2);
```

using named parameters, or using position parameters:

```
exec myproc ('a', 2);
```

Press the green "Run Statement" button in the toolbar to run the command.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me in great deal. Thanks once again.

Comment: what about out parameter ?